# Cannot decide structure of class with PDO

Tags: php, oop

I make a class and its PDO adaptor class.

```
class Entity {
    public $parent; // Int. Parent represent another Entity object.
}

class EntityAdaptor {
    public $db; // PDO obejct.
    public function save(Entity $entity) {..}
    public function load(int $id) {..}
}
```

While coding, I've noticed I cannot load parent object of Entity directly, or at least don't know how.

One thing I can try is something like below but cannot sure that is enough..

```
class Entity {
    protected $parentEntity;
    ..

    public function parent() {
        if(empty($this->parentEntity)) {
            $this->parentEntity = EntityAdaptor::load($this->parent);
        }

        return $this->parentEntity;
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is, in professional point of view, what is good structure(?) of class in this circumstance?

Comment: What exactly did you write and how did you know you cannot load?

Comment: Its because I seperate Entity and its save/load function as EntityAdaptor class. What I understand is, if I want to load parent of Entity from Entity object itself, like `Entity->parent()`, the class has have PDO inside.

Comment: and its bit weird but including PDO adaptor inside Entity class feels like some disaster because it copies PDO object for every implemented Entity object.

Comment: It's not a disaster, as long as you have not a copy but a reference. However anyway it is considered  a rather worse practice, as opposed to Data Mapper pattern which you're trying to implement. But still I fail to see your problem. Yes you need your entity adapter to load the parent entity, this way or another. So just load it. What's the problem? Why do you need pdo, not your entity adapter?

Comment: um... is it okay something like `$EntityAdaptor->loadEntity( $this->id )` inside Entity object? I know it works because I've done before but also thinks that its worse practice. However I can't go further because don't know other way..

Comment: I don't understand. What is loadEntity method? in the code above there is load() method only. Do you have your system working WITHOUT parent stuff at all?

Comment: I'm sorry. There's a bit of confusion. `load()` is right. Because the poor english skill, I can't explain my situation correctly and can't maintain proper wording at this moment. However, I'm trying to figure out data mapper pattern and other patterns from googling. Also thanks to your comment and past answers.

Comment: oh also I'm reading The only proper  PDO tutorial too. Its really fun and helpful!

Comment: I think you should implement your ideas without parent stuff first. Because to me, working with parent is no different from working with entity. As long as you can load the "main" entity, you can load the parent one as well. Yes I think that searching on Data Mappers with google is a good idea. As of my tutorial you may also like the [Fetching objects with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/objects) part. Thank you fro your kind words. Feel free to ask any questions